# Can't merge two LinearLayouts using addView for android app

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to merge two LinearLayouts like this:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
main.addView(namnLL,lp);
    hscrolla.addView(ll_scrolla,lp);
    scrolla.addView(hscrolla,lp);
    main.addView(scrolla,lp);
    setContentView(main, lp);
```

However, when I run the app, only the first "main" is visible.

Does anyone know what I've done wrong?

Edit: Here's some additional code:

```
LinearLayout main = new LinearLayout(this);
main.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

LinearLayout ll_scrolla=new LinearLayout(this);
ScrollView scrolla=new ScrollView(this);
HorizontalScrollView hscrolla=new HorizontalScrollView(this);

LinearLayout namnLL = new LinearLayout(this);
LinearLayout textrutaView = new LinearLayout(this);
textrutaView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

//Everything named something with "tv" are TextViews
namnLL.addView(tvNamn,lp);
textrutaView.addView(tv1,lp);
textrutaView.addView(tv2,lp);
textrutaView.addView(tv3,lp);
textrutaView.addView(tv4,lp);
textrutaView.addView(tv5,lp);

namnLL.addView(namnTV);
ll_scrolla.addView(textrutaView);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the `LinearLayout` orientation in `VERTICAL`, in this way:

```
main.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

default it is `HORIZONTAL`